# Create a second single.php file

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a second single.php for my WordPress theme.
The first single is used with `get_permalink()` but it's impossible to create another `single2.php`

How is this feasible?

I'd like to use the `single2.php` the same way as the regular `single.php`
I've seen some tutorials but every time they associate the `single2.php` with the creation of WP categories and I know it's doable without it. I just don't know how.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to load custom single.php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201069/how-to-load-custom-single-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open single.php in your HTML editor. Delete the contents of `single.php` and place the following code in it. Substitute the number 3 for the Category ID # you noted.

```
<?php
$post = $wp_query->post;
if ( in_category('3') ) {
    include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single2.php');
} else {
    include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single1.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201069/how-to-load-custom-single-php

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [Wordpress Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/), it could give you tips to do that :

You could create a `page-{slug}.php` or a `page-{id}.php` file for example, but it's not the nicest way as it's only for a specific slug or specific id.

I'd recommend to [create a template file](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/), where you can create your page. This template can be reuse for several pages !